# Operations on bytes in C#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, function, logic

I'm writing application to control LEDS on LPT.
I have everything working except this. 
This is one small function.

I have sth like that:

I want to build function that will take two argument and return one number:
In actual code those binary numers will be in hex. I put them there like that so that it's easier for you to visualize it.

Example1:

```
arg1 = 1100 1100
arg2 = 1001 0001
retu = 0100 1100
```

Example2:

```
arg1 = 1111 1111
arg2 = 0001 0010
retu = 1110 1101
```

Example3:

```
arg1 = 1111 0000
arg2 = 0010 0010
retu = 1101 0000
```

I have no idea how this function should look like.
I want it to be as fast as possible.

I'll call this function 200 times per second.

Comment: Clear as mud. First off, I have no idea what "I have sth like that:" means. Also, in your summary, 1+1=1, but in your examples, 1+1=0. ???

Comment: @Jonathan Wood I edit it

Comment: This is a programmer's website. Why would you think anything would be easier to visualise than hex? :-)

Comment: Your function is called "implication", and it is written a => b. It is equal to a & ~b.

Comment: @Joey, the colon-minus-closebracket notation is used in this instance to indicate a joke.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essentially, the set bits in the second argument are those you want removed. So you can simply *and* with the negated second argument:

```
byte Foo(byte a, byte b) {
  return (byte)(a & ~b);
}
```

Your examples at least follow this.

As [Alexandre C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373025/alexandre-c) notes in a comment to the question, the function is called an implication, i.e. *A* ⇒ *B*.

Comment: @Hooch: What mistake? It's still the same operation.